# Polynomial function of simple symmetric random walk and martingales

Tags: probability, probability-theory, martingales

**Problem:** Let $S_n$ denote the position of a simple random walk after $n$ steps, that is, $S_n=X_1+\cdots+X_n$ with $X_i$ i.i.d. and $P(X_i=1)=P(X_i=-1)=1/2.$
For which polynomials $g(x)$ will $g(S_n)$ be a martingale? (Here the coefficients of $g$ cannot depend on $n$.)

**My Thoughts:** I have the following. Let $g(x)=a_mx^m+a_{m-1}x^{m-1}+\cdots+a_0$ be a generic polynomial. Then $g(S_n)$ is a martingale if and only if
$$E[g(S_{n+1})\mid\mathcal F_n]=g(S_n)\quad\text{for all }n\geq1.$$
Hence if and only if
$$E\left[a_mS_{n+1}^m+a_{m-1}S_{n+1}^{m-1}+\cdots+a_0\mid\mathcal F_n\right]=a_mS_n^m+a_{m-1}S_n^{m-1}+\cdots+a_0.$$
So we need to compute the conditional expectation on the left. By linearity, we have
$$E\left[g(S_{n+1})\mid\mathcal F_n\right]=a_mE\left[S_{n+1}^m\mid\mathcal F_n\right]+a_{m-1}E\left[S_{n+1}^{m-1}\mid\mathcal F_n\right]+\cdots+a_0.$$
Now we look at each term separately. Using the binomial theorem and the fact that $X_{n+1}$ is independent of $\mathcal F_n$ we get
\begin{align*}
a_mE\left[S_{n+1}^m\mid\mathcal F_n\right]
&=a_mE\left[(S_n+X_{n+1})^m\mid\mathcal F_n\right]\\
&=a_mE\left[\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{m}{k}S_n^kX_{n+1}^{m-k}\mid\mathcal F_n\right]\\
&=a_m\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{m}{k}S_n^{k}E\left[X_{n+1}^{m-k}\mid\mathcal F_n\right]\\
&=a_m\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{m}{k}S_n^kE\left[X_{n+1}^{m-k}\right].
\end{align*}
From the calculation above we see that in order for the martingale property to be satisfied, the coefficients will have to depend on $n$, since so do the higher moments of $X_{n+1}$. Therefore, the only polynomials that satisfy the martingale property are $g(x)=x+a$ for constant $a$.

---

Do you agree with my reasoning above?
Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Why do the higher moments depend on $n$? Don't we have $\mathbb{E}[X_{n+1}^{m-k}] = 0,1$? $1$ if $m \equiv_2 k$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: @LucaMac Based on your comment, I did some reading and found that the moments of a Bernoulli random variable are always equal to $p$, so in this case, we have $E\left[X_{n+1}^{m-k}\right]=1/2$ whenever $m\ne k$. With this in mind, we still see that must have the claimed result since when we equate coefficients in the martingale property, that is the only way to achieve equality. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: You don't have a traditional Bernoulli, so it's a little bit different, they are either $0$ or $1$ depending on the parity of $m-k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, $X_{n+1}^{m-k}$ has the same distribution as $X_{1}^{m-k}$ hence the expectation of this term does not depend on $n$. We get that $E\left[X_{n+1}^{m-k}\right]=0$ if $m-k$ is odd and $E\left[X_{n+1}^{m-k}\right]=1$ if $m-k$ is even.

One finds that $2E\left[g(S_{n+1})\mid\mathcal F_n\right]=g(S_n-1)+g(S_n+1)$ hence $g(S_n)$ is a martingale if and only if
$$
2g(S_n)=g(S_n-1)+g(S_n+1)\mbox{ a.s.}.
$$
As $S_n$ takes the values $2k-n$, $0\leqslant k\leqslant n$, with positive probability, we get in particular that
$2g(n)=g(n-1)+g(n+1)$ for each $n$. Letting $P\colon x\mapsto 2g(x)-g(x-1)-g(x+1)$, we can see that $P$ is a polynomial having infinitely many roots hence
$2g(x)=g(x-1)+g(x+1)$ for each real number $x$. Now, defining $Q(x)=P(x)-P(x+1)$, we can see that $Q(x+1)=Q(x)$ hence $Q$ is constant and this implies that $P$ is a polynomial of degree one.